# HttpClient SocketTimeoutException handling

Tags: java, httpclient, socket-timeout-exception

I get data from `REST API server` using `HttpClient`.
Now I should handle when I can't get any response over 10 seconds from `API Server`.
So I did it like following

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpParams httpParams = httpClient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10000);

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("api server address");
httpPost.setParams(...);

HttpResponse response;
try{
    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);    
} catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
    httpPost.setParams(...); // change param
    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
}
```

It occured like
`invalid use of singleclientconnmanager: connection still allocated.`
It makes sense, but I don't know how to handle.

Comment: You have to use a new `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem

```
invalid use of singleclientconnmanager: connection still allocated.
```

occurs since you call the execute() method twice whenever control block goes in the exception block i.e. there is any exception.

```
try{
    // First Call
    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);    
} catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
    httpPost.setParams(...); // change param
    //Second Call
    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
}
```

Elegant way to handle this would be to use HTTPRequestRetryHandler
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d4e280